# Functions-framework won't run in windows command line after installing

Tags: python, functions-framework

Has anyone run into this issue before? I've done `pip install --user functions-framework` and been told a bunch of requirements are already satisfied.

When I then run `functions-framework --target=function` I get the error `'functions-framework' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **run** command prompt **as Administrator**.
2. Then uninstall functions-framework using the code `pip uninstall functions-framework`
3. Reinstall it by: `pip install functions-framework`
4. Go to your main.py directory and run `functions-framework --target=<YOUR_FUNCTION>`

Comment: Any luck on this ? Tried these steps from command prompt (admin mode) still getting the same error "'functions-framework' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Reza's answer worked for me. Does pip install / uninstall work for you in admin mode with other packages?

Answer (score 0):

After trying Reza's point and if it still doesn't work then try may be the below command. it works for me all the time.

functions-framework-python --target <<you_function>> --debug